# Run jar in background (windows & osx)

Tags: java, windows, macos

I have written a java client application that needs to run all the time.
The client needs to run on windows and also on osx computers.
Is there an - operating system independent - way to run the jar file in the background?

Comment: There is no OS-independent way to run a jar, whether in the background or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/index.html project. It allows to run the java code as daemon services.

Comment: I used the commons-daemon project to create the services/daemons. This works on windows, but when I try to install jsvc on linux (ubuntu) I always get the following error: *** Writing output files ***
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
sed: file ./confstatZsFeiM/subs-1.sed line 33: unterminated `s' command
config.status: creating Makedefs
sed: file ./confstatZsFeiM/subs-1.sed line 33: unterminated `s' command
config.status: creating native/Makefile
sed: file ./confstatZsFeiM/subs-1.sed line 33: unterminated `s' command
And this results in an empty make file.

Comment: @ToHe, I believe that there is a package jsvc for Ubuntu. Just try to apt-get / aptitude search jsvc. http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jsvc

Comment: I still have two minor issues. 1. When installing the service on windows I have to manually start it, using the Prunmgr executable. I tried using //ES & start commands, but that doesn't work. 2. In unix the daemon is installed & starts running immediately, but after a reboot, the daemon won't start automatically (-> .sh script command: $EXEC -home "$JAVA_HOME" -cp $CLASS_PATH -outfile $LOG_OUT -errfile $LOG_ERR $1 -pidfile $PID_FILE -jvm server $CLASS $CONFIGURATION_FILE). What am I missing here?

Comment: cannot comment on Windows platform, but for Ubuntu jsvc is not automatically started. You have to provide your own startup scripts